# SkPy: Skype guest login fails (403 forbidden)

Tags: python, skype

I'm using Python 3.11 with SkPy (installed via PyPI). I'm trying to perform a simple guest login:

```
from skpy import Skype

url = "<group chat invite link here>"
sk = Skype()
sk.conn.guestLogin(url, "guest")
sk.conn
```

Most of the time I get the following error:

```
self.tokens["skype"], self.tokenExpiry["skype"] = SkypeGuestAuthProvider(self).auth(url, name)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skpy/conn.py", line 832, in auth
   token = self.conn("POST", "{0}/api/v1/users/guests".format(SkypeConnection.API_JOIN),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skpy/conn.py", line 249, in __call__
   raise SkypeApiException("{0} response from {1} {2}".format(resp.status_code, method, url), resp)
skpy.core.SkypeApiException: ('403 response from POST https://join.skype.com/api/v1/users/guests', <Response [403]>)
```

but sometimes it works fine even though I'm not doing anything (like modifying conn.py). Any ideas on why it works like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've tried to change the url above, then it'll success,

but after few times it will go 403 again.

Which means you cannot keep creating guest, you can use `sk.loop()` to keep the service.